# Way to get the twos compliment decimal from binary?

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

I have a simple question, how do I get the twos compliment instead of the regular answer from binary? I have a program that does the booths algorithm but when it returns the decimal it gives me a number that's a bit too high, I'm doing 9 * -9 and the answer it gives is 65455. I just want to know if there is a way to get the twos compliment instead (-81). The binary I get from the code is 1111111110101111 which I know from looking around does equal -81 when finding the two's compliment, I just don't know how to get my program to recognize or say that.

Edit: I found a small fix, essentially just checking if the binary of the product equals the result I got, this is how I've been printing  the binary and converting it to a decimal, putting in the print area as The answer said something had to be done here, I got it working properly but would like to clean it up if I can

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
    int operand1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the second number: ");
    int operand2 = sc.nextInt();
    String answer = multiply(operand1, operand2);
    System.out.println("Final Product (binary): " + answer);
    int decimal=Integer.parseInt(answer,2); 
    if(operand1 * operand2 < 0) {
        int decProduct = operand1 * operand2;
        String biProduct = toBinary(decProduct, 16);
        if (biProduct.length() > 16) 
        {
            biProduct = biProduct.substring(biProduct.length() - 16);
        } 
        if(biProduct.equals(answer)) {
            decimal = decProduct;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final Answer (decimal): " + decimal);  
}
```

Comment: When you only have 16 bits you get to decide if one of the bits is a plus/minus sign leaving 15 bits for the number or you define the number to be positive and have all 16 bits.  Here you have a situation where you disagree with the JVM on which way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The computer has no idea what it means. It just has some memory and in that memory are bits. The bits that are in it, are e.g. `1111111110101111`.

What does that sequence mean? Who knows. The computer doesn't know or care.

It's the *print* code that decides. *IT* decides that this is to be taken in and then rendered such that the characters `-`, `8`, and `1` appear on your computer screen.

Thus, the error here, is in the print code. There is no converting required. The bit sequence is all the things, at once: It's `1111111110101111`, it's 65455, **and** it is -81. Which one is shown depends on how you print it.

Given that your print code isn't in the question, you're going to have to figure it out with this information.